# Fastest way to index a very large Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing

I have a very large knowledge graph in pandas dataframe format as follows.

This dataframe `KG` has more than 100 million rows:

```
                   pred     subj      obj
        0   nationality     BART      USA
        1  placeOfBirth     BART  NEWYORK
        2     locatedIn  NEWYORK      USA
      ...           ...      ...      ...
116390740     hasFather     BART   HOMMER
116390741   nationality   HOMMER      USA
116390743  placeOfBirth   HOMMER  NEWYORK
```

I tried to get a row from this `KG` with a specific value for subj and obj.

a) I tried indexing into `KG` by generating a boolean series using `isin()` function:

```
KG[KG['subj'].isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK']) & KG['obj'].isin(['USA', 'HOMMER'])]
```

b) I also tried indexing the `KG` using `query()` function:

```
KG = KG.set_index(['subj','obj'], drop=True)
KG = KG.sort_index()
subj_substitution = ['BART', 'NEWYORK']
obj_substitution= ['USA', 'HOMMER']    
KG.query(f"subj in {subj_substitution} & obj in {obj_substitution}
```

c) And I also tried to join two DataFrames using a `merge()` as shown below.

```
subj_df

      subj
0     BART
1  NEWYORK


obj_df

      obj
0     USA
1  HOMMER

merge_result = pd.merge(KG, subj_df, on = ['subj']).drop_duplicates()
merge_result = pd.merge(merge_result, obj_df, on = ['obj']).drop_duplicates()
```

These methods result in the following:

```
                   pred     subj      obj
        0   nationality     BART      USA
        2     locatedIn  NEWYORK      USA
116390740     hasFather     BART   HOMMER
```

I used the `timeit` function to check the time for each as shown below.

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: KG[(KG['subj'].isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK']) & (KG['obj'].isin(['USA', 'HOMMER'])))] , number=10)
```

The runtimes were:

| function | runtime |
| --- | --- |
| `isin()` | 35.6s |
| `query()` | 155.2s |
| `merge()` | 288.9s |

I think `isin()` is the fastest way to index a very large Dataframe.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me a faster way than this.

Comment: `pred`,`subj`,`obj` are all strings with low cardinality. Convert them to [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), then they'll get represented as integers under-the-hood. If you can post say 1K rows of your dataset as an attachment, I'll post the code.

Comment: Actually just tell us each column's cardinality: `KG.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=0)`

Comment: Won chul Shin: but that's just the first 6 lines replicated many times. It's not going to exercise the cardinality (small number of unique values).

Comment: Sorry 
I'll give you some new data, so you can try this. Thank you for your help.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rNjvvUJxM4LCn9qnWdyOhlWtwK--A577/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please tell us each column's cardinality, as asked: `KG.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=0)`?

Comment: Actually it's probably better performance to use a graph database like [`neo4j`](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally go with `isin` or `query with in`.

### Pandas doc says:

#### Performance of query()

DataFrame.query() using numexpr is slightly faster than Python for large frames.
Note: You will only see the performance benefits of using the numexpr engine with DataFrame.query() if your frame has more than approximately 200,000 rows.

Details about `query` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341369/pandas-why-query-instead-of-bracket-operator/67341422#67341422)

In your example when I tested `KG dataframe` with `shape (50331648, 3) - 50M+ rows and 3 column` using `query` and `isin` the performance results were almost same.

**isin**

```
%timeit KG[KG['subj'].isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK']) & KG['obj'].isin(['USA', 'HOMMER'])]
4.14 s ± 83.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**query with in operator**

```
%timeit KG.query("(subj in ['BART', 'NEWYORK']) and (obj in ['USA', 'HOMMER'])")
4.08 s ± 82.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**query with isin**

```
%timeit KG.query("(subj.isin(['BART', 'NEWYORK']))& (obj.isin(['USA', 'HOMMER']))")
4.99 s ± 210 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Test Data**

```
d="""pred,subj,obj
nationality,BART,USA
placeOfBirth,BART,NEWYORK
locatedIn,NEWYORK,USA
hasFather,BART,HOMMER
nationality,HOMMER,USA
placeOfBirth,HOMMER,NEWYORK"""
KG = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
for i in range(23):
    KG = pd.concat([KG,KG])
KG.shape # (50331648, 3)
```

If `performance + code readability(maintenance)` is concerned, then atleast for complex queries I would go with `query function`.