# Subsetting dataframe by same values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

| code_1 | code_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a1 |
| a2 | a1 |
| b1 | b2 |
| b3 | b3 |

What I want to do here is that I want to subset the dataframe by selecting the rows that have same values in 'code_1' and 'code_2'

The final output would look like below:

| code_1 | code_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a1 |
| b3 | b3 |

Thank you

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve it?

Comment: df_new = df[df['code_1'].values == df['code_2'].values]

Comment: I think the code itself is wrong.

Comment: When you include your attempts to solve it and the error messages, if any, you’ll most likely get a better response. It helps people know where you are coming from and let’s them know you’ve tried to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

**Code**

```
df.query('code_1 == code_2')
```

**Output**

```
    code_1  code_2
0   a1      a1
3   b3      b3
```

**If we want the index to be sequential**

```
df.query('code_1 == code_2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
    code_1  code_2
0   a1      a1
1   b3      b3
```

More details about query can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341369/pandas-why-query-instead-of-bracket-operator/67341422#67341422)