# choose rows to another dataframe and drop rows by conditional in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have simple dataframe and i would like separate it.

| Make | Model | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 1 serie | 2007 |
| Kia | K7 | 2012 |
| BMW | 6 serie | 1982 |
| BMW | 6 serie | 1987 |
| BMW | X3 | 2006 |
| Kia | Bongo | 2000 |

i need take cars where (Year >= 2000) and put it to another dataframe, at the same time i would like leave the rest of the data (Year < 2000). No use `inplace = True` because as far as I know it is supposed to be removed from pandas. I did it using `.loc` but is there a better solution?
my solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Make': {0: 'BMW', 1: 'Kia', 2: 'BMW', 3: 'BMW', 4: 'BMW', 5: 'Kia'}, 
        'Model': {0: '1 serie', 1: 'K7', 2: '6 serie', 3: '6 serie', 4: 'X3', 5: 'Bongo'}, 
        'Year': {0: 2007, 1: 2012, 2: 1982, 3: 1987, 4: 2006, 5: 2000}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cars)


df_2000 = df.loc[df["Year"]>=2000]
df = df.loc[df["Year"]<2000]
```

Comment: Looks good to me, you can save and reuse the mask: `mask = df["Year"]>=2000 ; df_2000 = df.loc[mask] ; df = df[~mask]`

Answer (score 0):

For your use case you can take advantage of the [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function :

```
df_2000 = df.query("Year >= 2000")
df = df.query("Year < 2000")
```

For Simple cases it provides easier and cleaner code.

You can read more about the pros and cons of `query` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341369/pandas-why-query-instead-of-bracket-operator/67341422#67341422).